# jQuery button style only being applied to buttons in first page of Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

I've tried to search the internet for a similar issue, but I don't know how to word it.

I have a [Datatable](http://www.datatables.net) which shows data on multiple pages. In each row I have a button with the class "opt". Then in the document ready function, I initialize the buttons with the follow:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".opt" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-gear",
        secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
      },
      text: false
    });
});
```

When I load the page, however, this jQuery styling has only been applied to buttons on the first page. The buttons on the other page show up as a normal button would. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Could it be that the page change event on the Datatable triggers a draw function? In this case the buttons on the other Datatable pages do not really exist until they are drawn.

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue. But how might I check?

Comment: I added an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes so this is the case like I mentioned above.

```
// Re-draws the table on update.
table.draw();
```

Is a function that is triggered when there is a change in the table.

What you would want to do is follow harco's suggestion.
You would need to add a snippet of code like the following, my example will use Jquery.

```
// On every pagination click
// paginate_button is a class given to the pagination buttons in the datatable.
$('.paginate_button').click(function(){

   // You might have to add a setTimeout function 
   // here to make sure the datatable is done loading.

   $( ".opt" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-gear",
        secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
      },
      text: false
    });
});
```

Info on the datatable events http://www.datatables.net/manual/events

This is what you should try as shown on the datatable page.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.on( 'draw', function () {
    // your code here
} );
```

What this will do is it will setup your function on the updated datatable that was re-drawn.

Hope this is a good example and explanation

Comment: Applying this, I get the following error:
`JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'onclick'`

Comment: it is actually supposed to just 'click'

Comment: What resource did you use to come to this answer? I pored over the Datatables .js file and couldn't find anything I understood as useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the code runs after each page is loaded. The document ready function is only called when the initial document (with the first page of data) is loaded. When you add new data to the data table you should go through all the newly added elements with class ".opt" and turn them into styled buttons.

The Datatable plugin has an [event](http://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) which is triggered after the table is redrawn. You should use it to style your buttons again.

```
function initButtons() {
    $( ".opt" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-gear",
        secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
      },
      text: false
    });
}

// Document ready
$(function() {
  initButtons();
});

// Assuming "table" is the variable name of your datatable
table.on('draw', initButtons);
```

Comment: The Datatable is not editable. Are you suggesting that the pages of the Datatable aren't loaded before document ready?

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue. I also use jQuery to initialize each of the buttons to bring up a dropdown menu, and the buttons on pages 2+ show the dropdown fine.

Comment: Yes, i think the pages of the table are loaded when required. You can check this with the developer tools.

Can you post the code for the dropdown ?